# Multiple joins in SQLAlchemy often fails with 'sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError'

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm uncertain how to properly do multiple joins with SQLalchemy.

I'm attempting to get a result from the get request which provides a list of narratives `NarrativeModel` which contain one or more references `ReferenceModel` where the `publishDate` is a given value. In the below example this is `2022-03-09`

However, I can't figure out how to perform a join across `Narrative`, `NarrativeReference` and `Reference`. And my attempts mostly end with the following or similar: `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object expected, got object of type <class 'flask_sqlalchemy.model.DefaultMeta'> instead`

## Narrative Model

```
class NarrativeModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "narrative"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    ownerProfileID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('profile.id'), nullable=False)
    scheduled = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    ongoing = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
```

## NarrativeReference Model (joining table)

```
class NarrativeReferenceModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "narrativereference"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    narrativeID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('narrative.id'), nullable=False)
    referenceID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('reference.id'), nullable=False)
```

## ReferenceModel

```
class ReferenceModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "reference"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    langCode= db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    isGov = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    domain = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    suffix = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    publishDate = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    addedDate = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    youtubeId = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    langCheck = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
```

## Get request

```
class GlobalNarrativesByTodaysUpdates (Resource):

    #RETURNS ALL AVAILABLE NARRATIVES
    # Called with: curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request GET http://localhost:8080/narratives
    def get(self):
        schema = NarrativeSchema()
        result = NarrativeModel.query\
                .join(NarrativeReferenceModel, NarrativeModel.id == NarrativeReferenceModel.narrativeID)\
                .filter(ReferenceModel, ReferenceModel.publishDate == '2022-03-09').all()


        db.session.close()
        return schema.dump(result, many=True), 200
```

A working SQL statement which satisfies my needs is:

```
select distinct narrative.title, narrative.date from narrative, narrativereference
where narrativereference.narrativeID = narrative.id
and narrativereference.referenceID in (select id from reference where publishDate = '2022-03-09')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by using simple joins as the relationship is already defined in the model

```
    def get(self):
        schema = NarrativeSchema()
        result = NarrativeModel.query\
            .join(NarrativeReferenceModel)\
            .join(ReferenceModel)\
            .filter(ReferenceModel.addedDate == '2022-03-09').all()

        db.session.close()
        return schema.dump(result, many=True), 200
```